# python checking user input for number in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function below which is part of my big main function, what I want this function to do is that whenever called, I want the function to check if the user input is 
a number or not. If it is a number it will return the number and break.
But if it is not a number I want it to loop again and again.when I try to 
run it, it gives me unexpected an error:

```
unexpected eof while parsing
```

can any body help me what I am missing or how I should rearrange my code? thank you!

```
def getnumber():
    keepgoing==True
    while keepgoing:
        number = input("input number: ") 
        result1 = number.isdigit()

        if result1 == 1:
            return number
            break
        elif keepgoing==True:
```

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: And is that all of it? It seems to end rather suddenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neater and clearer what to do what you are already doing:

```
def getnumber():
    while True:
        number = input("Input number: ")
        if number.isdigit():
            return number
```

That's all you need, the extra variables are superfluous and the `elif` at the end makes no sense. You don't need to check booleans with `== True` or `== 1`, you just do `if condition:`. And nothing happens after `return`, your `break` will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the last line:

```
elif keepgoing==True:
```

It's waiting for the rest of the file after the `:`.

Side note, it should be a single `=` in the first part, and can just be written simpler as well.

```
def getnumber():
    while True:
        number = input("input number: ")
        result1 = number.isdigit()
        if result1:
            return number
```

Since you're inside the while loop, it'll keep executing. Using `return` will end the while loop, as will `break`ing and exiting the program. It will wait for `input` as well each time, though.

Comment: when I deleted the last one, it is not asking me for an input.

Answer (score 0):

While assigning you have used `keepgoing == True`, I think it should be `keepgoing=True`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works on my machine, although I *am* running Python 2.7

```
def get_num():
    while True: #Loop forever
        number_str = raw_input("> Input a number: ") #Get the user input
        if number_str.isdigit(): #They entered a number!
            return int(number_str) #Cast the string to an integer and return it
```

I used `raw_input` rather than `input`, because `raw_input` gives you the exact string the user entered, rather than trying to evaluate the text, like `input` does. (If you pass the `12` to `input`, you'll get the number 12, but if you pass `"12"`, you'll get the string `'12'`. And, if you pass `my_var`, you'll get whatever value was in `my_var`).

Anyway, you should also know that `isdigit()` returns whether or not the string has only digits in it and at least one character - that is *not* the same thing as *isNumber()*. For instance, `"123".isdigit()` is True, but `"123.0".isdigit()` is False. I also simplified your loop logic a bit.