# I can not use < or > in def function

Tags: python

#Here is part of my code.
money = 100

```
def bet():
    print(f"You have ${money}.")
    print("How many would you like to bet?")
    bet = int(input())
    while not bet > 0 or not bet < money:   #It gives me error if i wrote < or >.
        print(f"Type the value between [1]-[{money}].")
        bet()
    else:
        game(bet)
```

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a simple loop.

Comment: You reassigned `bet` to some other value, overwriting the reference to the original function thus rendering `bet` not a function to be called (thus `bet()` will result in `object is not callable`).  Also it would be good to search online on just the task you are stuck at, such as this thread on [checking user input for number in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450116/python-checking-user-input-for-number-in-a-while-loop).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion, so even though you are creating a local variable with the same name as your function, that's OK, because you won't *need* the name of your function.

```
def bet():
    while True:
        print(f"You have ${money}.")
        print("How many would you like to bet?")
        bet = int(input())
        if 0 < bet <= money:
            break
        print(f"Type the value between [1]-[{money}].")

    game(bet)
```